# How to solve "User is not in sudoers file, incident reported"

Tags: macos, sudo

I added

```
"Syammala Naidu" ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to `/etc/sudoers`, rebooted and logged in as Syammala Naidu and run `sudo -i`. Sudo tells me: `user not in sudoers file, incident Reported`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/838/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sudo` exclusively uses account names, not the user's full name. As a hint, **account names don't contain spaces**, so "Syammala Naidu" is not correct.

To find out a user's account name:

1. Open Terminal and run:

   ```
   id -un
   ```

or, alternatively:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Select Users & Groups.
3. If necessary, click the lock on the bottom left corner of the window and type an administrator's name and password to unlock the preference pane.
4. Right-click the account and select `Advanced Options...`.
5. Locate the `Account name` property:

   [image]

Use that account name in `/etc/sudoers`. To edit the file, use `visudo`. For more information, check [man visudo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/visudo.8.html) and [man sudoers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sudoers.5.html).